# Which design pattern should be used in this use case?

Tags: java, validation, design-patterns, xmlbeans

I am working on app where I have to write custom validation on some xmlbean oject, basically to see so and so fields with proper values exist or not. Now those objects are generated from diff schema. I am using validation provided by xmlbeans against the schema but there are some more business validation needs to be done for these objects before it is being processed further.
Can somebody suggest any design pattern for this use case?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your own **validator** interface:

```
interface Validator <T extends XmlBean> {
    boolean validate(T bean);
}
```

Implement it for each classyou are dealing with, you can provide a **factory** class to get the **validator** for each bean class by implementing the following interface:

```
interface IValidatorFactory {
    public <T extends XmlBean> Validator<T> getValidator(Class<T> clazz);
}

class ValidatorFactory implements IValidatorFactory {
    private final Map<Class<? extends XmlBean>, Validator<? extends XmlBean>> map =
        new HashMap<Class<? extends XmlBean>, Validator<? extends XmlBean>>();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public <T extends XmlBean> Validator<T> getValidator(Class<T> clazz) {
        return (Validator<T>)map.get(clazz);
    }

    public <T extends XmlBean> void registerValidator(Class<T> clazz, Validator<T> validator) {
        map.put(clazz, validator);
    }
}
```

Comment: looks promising. I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially add your own custom pre- and post-set hooks to your generated XmlBeans classes.  To add add the hooks you need to create an `.xsdconfig` file and provide a some `preSet()` and `postSet()` static methods that can be called.

For an example, see:

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-xmlbeanse/?ca=dgr-eclipse-1

And also:

http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/xmlbeans/trunk/test/cases/xbean/extensions/prePostFeature/readOnlyBean/po.xsdconfig?revision=HEAD&view=markup

http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/xmlbeans/trunk/test/src/xmlobject/extensions/prePostFeature/readOnlyBean/existing/FooHandler.java?revision=HEAD&view=markup